# Using javascript replace to replace numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, replace, numbers

I have a string

```
var x='abcdefg1234abcdefg';
```

I want to replace `1234` with `555` using the `x.replace()` function like

```
x=x.replace(stuff here)
```

I tried to pass `'1234','555'` as the parameters but it's not working.

Any clues? thanks

Edit:
The string is in a hidden `<input>` field. The value of it is:

```
<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="400" height="385">
 <param name="movie" value="player.swf" /> <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
 <param name="flashvars" value="provider=http&file=files/videos/10.file" />
 <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="player.swf" width="400" height="385" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" flashvars="provider=http&file=files/videos/10.file&image=preview.jpg"/>
</object>
```

I want to replace the width value and the height value to values stored in `sb_width` and `sb_height`.

Comment: Can you post _exactly_ what you tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you've described should have worked:

```
var x = 'abcdefg1234abcdefg';
x = x.replace('1234', '555');
alert(x); // alerts abcdefg555abcdefg
```

But note that `replace` when given a string will only replace the first one. To replace more, use a regex with the `g` flag (for "global"):

```
var x = 'abcdefg1234abcdefg1234xxx';
x = x.replace(/1234/g, '555');
alert(x); // alerts abcdefg555abcdefg555xxx
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/izegu4)

Comment: yes i am asking for the regex , i have the value spreaded all over the string ...

Comment: Thanks , it worked :) . i just used the regex inside doublequotes ex "/1234/i" and used I instead of G ... thanks again

Comment: @Ronan: Glad that helped, but there's no need for the double quotes, literal regexes are fine (preferred, if anything).

Answer (score 0):

following code works, tried now:

```
var bla='dfasfdas123dfasfas';
alert(bla.replace('123','555'));
```

Tried debugging in firebug or sth? Give us the exact code snippet you are trying

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't string replacement at all.  You use jQuery I hope?

```
$("$player").attr("width", sb_width);
$("$player").attr("height", sb_height);

$("$player").children("embed").attr("width", sb_width);
$("$player").children("embed").attr("height", sb_height);
```

String replacement is not the way to go here.  You'd need to hardcode the initial values, might replace an unintended similar string, the code doesn't really communicate your intention (to change height/width, not to manipulate strings)