# How to replace a string with a number with another string number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that contains a value that looks like this.

`somevalueshere=123&page=3&someothervalues=123`

and I want to replace the number **3** with **1**.
So it would look like `page=1`

The number is always a positive whole number like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

All I have so far is

```
.replace("page=" + 'some number reg ex here', "page=1")
```

Comment: yes, sorry I updated my post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using javascript replace to replace numbers in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178227/using-javascript-replace-to-replace-numbers-in-a-string)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That doesn't look for a pattern before the number, it just replaces the number anywhere.

Comment: So, the question is, do we want users to have to think or not? Or learn regex rather than coming back to SO every time? Apparently not. How about http://stackoverflow.com/q/1090948/215552? That will let them change any part of the query string they want.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression for a number (without decimals) is `\d+`. `\d` matches any numeric digit, and `+` means at least one of the preceding pattern.

```
str = str.replace(/\bpage=\d+/, 'page=1');
```

This is very basic regular expression syntax. If you don't already know it, you should read the tutorial at http://www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: Could you please explain the regex before I upvote it

Comment: @Barmar, really? You couldn't find a dupe for this? Do you really need more rep? :P

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sometimes it's easier to write a simple answer than go searching for things like this. The search terms tend to be too generic.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This isn't a generic forum. Please take your salt elsewhere

Comment: @CarlMarkham This isn't a help site. We're compiling a library of high-quality questions and answers, not collection of duplicate questions.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Feel free to vote to close as a dupe, and I'll use my dupe-hammer to complete it.

Comment: @Barmar Done. [I'm mostly just frustrated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339261/215552)...